# mocha test mock/spy imported library using testdouble.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing

my module requires an external dependencies: [downloadjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/downloadjs) that exports a function not Object

```
import download from 'downloadjs' // download is a function
```

### my function

```
const onExport = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  let data = getState().get('data')
  let csv = mapDataToCsv(data)

  download(csv, "export-result.csv", "text/csv");
  // dispatch something else
}
```

### unit testing

```
import download from 'downloadjs'
import td from 'testdouble'

// test case
it('unparse JSON to CSV', () => {
  td.replace('downloadjs') // no this doesn't work

  let store = createStore(reducer, initialState, middleware);
  store.dispatch(target.onExport()); // action calls

  let expected = td.matchers.contains('FOO,SUCCESS')
  // error it calls real download function not mock
  td.verify(download(expected, "export-result.csv", "text/csv")) 
  td.reset()
})
```

### problems

I tried to mock/replacing `downloadjs` to verify that it called with valid data.

neither `td.replace(download)` nor `td.replace('downloadjs')` works

the document says you shouldn't mock/replacing external library:

[Why doesn't td.replace() work with external CommonJS modules?](https://github.com/testdouble/testdouble.js/blob/master/docs/B-frequently-asked-questions.md#why-doesnt-tdreplace-work-with-external-commonjs-modules)

then how do I test this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a wrapper around the functionality that exists within the 3rd party library (downloadjs in this case) and use `td.replace` to mock your wrapper.

**your function**

```
var downloadCSV = require('./downloadCSV.js')

module.exports = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
    downloadCSV('goats')
}
```

**the new wrapper dependency**

```
// downloadCSV.js
var download = require('downloadjs')

module.exports = (data) => {
    download(data, 'export-result.csv', 'text/csv')
}
```

**the unit test**

```
describe('csv exporter', () => {
    var subject, downloadCSV
    beforeEach(() => {
        downloadCSV = td.replace('../../lib/downloadCSV.js')
        subject     = require('../../lib/code.js')
    })

    describe('downloading csv', () => {
        it('works', () => {
            subject()()
            td.verify(downloadCSV('goats'))
        })
    });
});
```

**notes**

1. note the double invocation of `subject()()` as you have a function which returns a function in your code under test.
2. I used the `node` example folder structure available in the test double repo to structure these tests: https://github.com/testdouble/testdouble.js/tree/master/examples/node
3. I've uploaded a repository with my sample code for you to play around with. https://github.com/davemo/td-replace-helper
4. I did not include the Redux specific code nor use ES6 style imports to avoid having to pull in too many dependencies in the example repo.
5. You may need to massage your use of ES6 style imports in order to facilitate the use of `td.replace`, check out this comment thread for more information: https://github.com/testdouble/testdouble.js/issues/51#issuecomment-207780628

Comment: thanks for clear examples. so the wrapper is untestable (needs integration test) but it makes sense to me :)

Comment: the wrapper is testable in an isolation/unit test by using `td.replace`, but yes if you want to validate the actual functionality of `downloadjs` you would need a more integrated test that crossed that boundary.